# Using JNA for accessing tooltip from windows

Tags: java, winapi, tooltip, jna

i am started experimenting with JNA to access every tooltip from windows. For this i am sending TTM_GETTOOLINFO message continuously to window. Below is my code...

```
public class Test {

     public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
     User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
     HWND GetForegroundWindow();  // add this
     int SendMessageA(HWND hwnd, int msg, int num1, TOOLINFO f );
    // int SendMessageW(HWND hwnd, int msg, int num1, TOOLINFO f );
   }


    public class TOOLINFO extends Structure
    {
        public int      cbSize;
        public int      uFlags;
        public HWND      hwnd;
        public UINT_PTR  uId;
        public RECT      rect;
        public HINSTANCE hinst;
        public char []    lpszText;

        TOOLINFO()
        {
            lpszText = new char[512];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Test().go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        TOOLINFO tt = new TOOLINFO();
        int WM_USER = 0x0400;
        HWND hwnd ;
        int i=0;
        while(true)
        {
            hwnd= User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
            try
            {
                i=User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageA(hwnd,WM_USER+8, 0, tt);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        if(i!=0)
            System.out.println("Tooltip :"+tt.lpszText);
                }
    }
}
```

But its not working. I am using window 8. I found two version of commctrl.h on web. One is showing that TTM_GETTOOLINFOA= WM_USER+8 TTM_GETTOOLINFOW= WM_USER+53 and other is showing TTM_GETTOOLINFOA= WM_USER+9 TTM_GETTOOLINFOW= WM_USER+54. However i tried with every combination with both SendMessageA and W. So i think there are some fundamental mistakes. So anyone can plz help me in the same. Accessing tooltip from JNA.

```
public class JnaTest2 {

      public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
      User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
      HWND GetForegroundWindow();  // add this
      int SendMessageW(HWND hwnd,int msg ,WPARAM w,TOOLINFOW lparam);
  }
    public class TOOLINFOW extends Structure
    {
        public int      cbSize;
        public int      uFlags;
        public HWND      hwnd;
        public UINT_PTR  uId;
        public RECT      rect;
        public HINSTANCE hinst;
        public Pointer pszText = new Memory(512);
        LPARAM l;
        Pointer lpReserved=null;
    }
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    new JnaTest2().go();
}
public void go()
{
    int WM_USER = 0x0400;
    TOOLINFOW tt = new TOOLINFOW();
    tt.cbSize=tt.size();
    System.out.println(tt.size());
    HWND hwnd ;
    int j=0;
    while(true)
    {
        hwnd=User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
        tt.hwnd=hwnd;
        try
        {
            j=User32.INSTANCE.SendMessageW(hwnd,WM_USER+53,new WPARAM(0),tt);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(j!=0)
            System.out.println("Tooltip :"+tt.pszText.getString(0));

    }
}
```

}

Comment: on my computer i searched Commctrl.h and found that TTM_GETTOOLINFOA= WM_USER+8 and TTM_GETTOOLINFOW= WM_USER+53. 9 and 54 are for TTM_SETTOOLINFO. Thats why i am using 8 in above code.

Comment: Anyoneee plz... some direction is going to spare my week...

Comment: You need different definitions of `TOOLINFO` depending on whether you're using `-A` or `-W` (`byte[]` for ascii and `char[]` for unicode).

Comment: I don't know what the normal usage is supposed to look like, but don't you need to initialize the data in `TOOLINFO`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As i said i have tried with every combination... using the byte array is also part of it. And what do you mean by initializing...!! i am initializing the char array and i dont think that i have to initialize the other public member. As i am new to JNA I am too confused about whole pattern of my code so do you really think that actual mistake is in that part i mean initialization or something...!! and other parts of code is right...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`TTM_GETTOOLINFOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- Use [`SendMessageW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- Initialize the `hWnd` and `cbSize` fields of [`TOOLINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
  `lpszText` must be of pointer type, not an inline array.  You can use `Memory`, with a field type of `Pointer`.  Make sure it's big enough.
- You are missing `lParam` (type `LPARAM`) and `lpReserved` (type `Pointer`) fields.

Edit your question to show how you implemented each of these things and the corresponding result.

**EDIT**

Check `Native.getLastError()` to see if the method call resulted in an error.  It won't throw an exception.

Comment: plz have a look on edited question. i am not sure on your 4th point. On some post of jna i read that i can use directly my structure name in method signature. so not using LPARAM and MSDN says that lpReserved should always be null. But code is still not working and even not giving any Exception.

Comment: I also tried with SendMessageA TOOLINFOA TTM_GETTOOLINFOA...just have no idea that where i am wrong. Without any Exception or Error i am totally hopeless. Just watching my code again and again. Also tried changing the size of allocating memory with different Memory size.

Comment: The last two parameters need to be `public`.  Are you certain that the `SencMessage` call and struct are supposed to use the same `hwnd` value?

Comment: Use `Pointer.getWideString(0)` to extract the native string, since you're using the unicode version.

Comment: Yes i think... [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it is the handle of owner window which have the tooltip control. We have to use it in sendMessage() and TOOLINFO structure [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).And native.getLastError() is giving 0 when mouse pointer is not on tool. When i move mouse pointer to any tooltip control its giving 1400. I found on MSDN that 1400 error code indicates "Invalid Window Handel" but i am giving the right window handel. Any suggestion?

Comment: There may be an issue accessing information from a separate process if your Java application is not being run in administrator mode.

Comment: i mean i have tested the GetForegrouWindow with GetWindowText and it is always returning the correct title.

Comment: how to run a java application in administrator mode..?

Comment: Write a .BAT file which invokes your command, then right-click on that .BAT file and select "run as administrator".

Comment: .BAT file solution is not working also tried starting netbeans with Run as Administrator but no effect. Anyways thanks for your support. WIN APIs are also like IE Sometimes it WORKS sometimes just NOT. :-). And i think it is something to do with "Invalid window handel". I will post the result if any comes.

Comment: You might try using a window handle from the Java process itself to ensure that you have both access and a valid window handle.

Comment: I didnt understand your last suggestion. How to do that. Window handle from java process.!

Comment: and if GetWindowText and GetForgroundWindow is just working perfectly than dosent it mean that i have valid handle and access.!